# If all three radio buttons are false, don't validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have three different blocks of code, with radio buttons.

The only thing that changes are id and the name of them.

What I need is: if all radio buttons are checked on the `value="false"` (the user choose to check all the "no"), the form won't be valid.

I'm currently using jQuery validation and all I got to have is that radio buttons are all required.

I tried with this code, but it's not working.

```js
registerForm.validate({
      rules: {
        'data': {
          required: {
            depends: function() {
              return $('.yesandno').is(':checked').val() === "false";
            }
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="yes-balance" tabindex='9' name="data" value="true" />
  <label for="yes-balance" class="yes">YES</label>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="no-balance" tabindex='9' name="data" value="false" />
  <label for="no-balance" class="no">NO</label>
</div>
```

EDIT: 
In the end, I mixed Ele's code-reply with the jQuery validation plugin that it is used on the portal I'm working on. 
This is the code:

```
    submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#btn-register').click(() => {
              if ($('.yesandno:checked[value="false"]').size() === 3) {
                return false;
              } else {
                form.submit();
              }
            });
        }
```

Comment: "it's not working" - what's the error? You have syntax errors so I would look at your code carefully...

Comment: I wrote a very little part of the entire page I'm workin on, I just want to get to know if there's a way in jQuery validation or how I can manage to do that in other ways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With a jQuery selector you can accomplish that**

```
$('.yesandno:checked[value="false"]').size() === 3
```

Look at this code snippet

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  if ($('.yesandno:checked[value="false"]').size() === 3) {
    console.log('All radionbuttos were checked to NO');
  } else {
    console.log('Either at least one Radionbutto is YES or a (YES/NO) radiobutton was not still checked!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="yes-balance" tabindex='9' name="data" value="true" />
  <label for="yes-balance" class="yes">YES</label>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="no-balance" tabindex='9' name="data" value="false" />
  <label for="no-balance" class="no">NO</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="yes-balance" tabindex='9' name="data2" value="true" />
  <label for="yes-balance" class="yes">YES</label>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="no-balance" tabindex='9' name="data2" value="false" />
  <label for="no-balance" class="no">NO</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="yes-balance" tabindex='9' name="data3" value="true" />
  <label for="yes-balance" class="yes">YES</label>
  <input type="radio" class="yesandno" id="no-balance" tabindex='9' name="data3" value="false" />
  <label for="no-balance" class="no">NO</label>
</div>
<br>
<button>Click to see selected value!</button>
```

See? the condition is `true` when `size === 3`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I managed to make it work with your code. 
I had to change it a bit, since I'm using jQuery validation plugin: 
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $('#btn-register').click(() => {
                      if ($('.yesandno:checked[value="false"]').size() === 3) {
                        return false;
                      } else {
                        form.submit();
                      }
                    });
                },

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter and check the length:

```js
// this filter will only return radios that are checked and have a value of false
$('.yesandno').filter(function() {
   return this.checked && this.value === "false";
}).length === 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check at least one `true` value to pass your validation instead of checking all three radio buttons for `false` to fail validation. This will be helpful to scale your HTML radio options without having to change the JQuery code again and again for the length match for `false` options selection.

```
function passValidation(){
    $('.yesandno').filter(function() {
       return this.checked && this.value === "true";
    }).length > 0;
}
```

Call `passValidation()` function during validation and if it returns `true` then there is at least one radio button with `Yes` option selected. And `false` from `passValidation()` means no `Yes` option is selected.